# Getting error on reindexing from terminal in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have installed fresh magento 2 in my local server. Now when i am trying to reindex from my terminal in Ubuntu its givng error i.e.:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Prior i have installed magento 2, but it was working fine.

[image]

Comment: check your layout xml , there can be mismatch opening and closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your php DOM extension missing please check whether the extension is enabled and listed using the command php -m.

Check the below URL's for needed php extensions for magento2

1.http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#required-php-extensions

2.http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#required-php-extensions